# Javascript validation accepting when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a script that is checking my email and date fields.
They will still accept a bad date. What am I doing wrong? I am new to regex.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btn-submit').click(function() {
    $('.error').hide();

    var hasError = false;
    var payError = false;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    var ccdate = /^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/((2013)|(20[1-4][0-9]))$/;
```

//validate email

```
var emailaddressVal = $("#mail").val();
if(emailaddressVal == '') {
  $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your email address.</span>');
  hasError = true;
}
else if(!emailReg.test(emailaddressVal)) {
  $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid email address.</span>');
  hasError = true;
}
```

// This checks if the drop down option is selected to show billing fields.

```
if ( ($("#selection").val() == '') ) {
    $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please select an option.</span>');
    hasError = true;
 }

if ( ($("#selection").val() == 'charge') ) {
    //validate cctype
    if ( ($("#cctype").val() == '') ) {
      $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please select a credit card type.</span>');
      payError = true;
    }
```

//validate ccdate

```
    var ccdate = $("#ccdate").val();
    if ( ccdate == '') {
      $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter a date</span>');
      payError = true;
    }
    else if(!date.test(ccdate)) {
        $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid date.</span>');
        payError = true;
      }

    if(payError == true) { return false; }
}

if(hasError == true) { return false; }

});
```

My form has several input fields. I have a drop down that will show the billing table with all the billing fields. 
I am trying to get it to only accept MM/YYYY as a valid credit card date.
This seems to accept any string.

Thank you

Comment: The receiver is the regex: `!ccdate.test(date)`

Comment: You're reusing the variable name `ccdate` for two different purposes. Try renaming the variable that your RegExp is referenced by to just `date` (or better `datePattern` and change it in both places in your code).

Comment: Oh I see, he's re-assigning `ccdate`....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var ccdate = $("#ccdate").val();
```

Here, you’re overwriting the regular expression from here:

```
var ccdate = /^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/((2013)|(20[1-4][0-9]))$/;
```

Change the name of the regular expression to `date`. Also, `2013` and `20[1-4][0-9]` don’t need to be in groups.